# using vim for FCEDIT with a special textwidth

Tags: bash, vim

I am using Kubuntu 20.04, but this is a bash issue I'm annoyed about it since tens of years.

I have .vimrc and .viminfo on a USB stick. Thus to use vim as editor for FCEDIT, I setup

```
export FCEDIT='vim -u /media/WE_MNT_HISTFIL/root/.vimrc'
```

and this invokes vim with option

```
textwidth=66
```

for normal applications to have automatic word wrap etc.

On the other side I have often to call "fc" for very long lines, e.g. in scripts.

After each call of "fc" I have to set:

```
textwidth=0
```

To avoid this aggrivating circumstance I have long googled and then developed a function as follows:

```
alias fc1='WEfunc_my_fc_alias'

function WEfunc_my_fc_alias() {

  /bin/cp -f "/media/WE_MNT_HISTFIL/root/.vimrc" /tmp/WEx_vimrc_tmp

  echo "set textwidth=0" >>/tmp/WEx_vimrc_tmp

  export FCEDIT='vim -u /tmp/WEx_vimrc_tmp'

  fc -1 -1

  export FCEDIT='vim -u /media/WE_MNT_HISTFIL/root/.vimrc'

}
```

My question is, please, do someone know a simpler sulution?

As I know, bash does not allow another way.

Comment: Hello. If this has been a problem for 10 years why bring it up now?

Answer (score 0):

If only for `fc` the `vim` configuration must be different, you could work with an alias like:

```
fc='FCEDIT="vim" fc'
```

This changed the environmental variable `FCEDIT` just before (and just for) invoking the fc command. You could specify another custom vim profile in between the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read through the vim man page: you're looking for the `-c` option. You don't have to rewrite any vim rc files.
Using a shell wrapper function helps with the quoting.

```bsh
unalias fc
fc() { FCEDIT='vim -c "set tw=0"' builtin fc "$@"; }
```

... no apparently that doesn't work. It looks like bash does not respect the inner quotes in the FCEDIT value and executes this

```bsh
vim -c '"set' 'tw=0"' temp_file_name
```

However, this does work:

```bsh
fcvim () { vim -c "set tw=0" "$@"; }
fc() { FCEDIT=fcvim builtin fc "$@"; }
```

---

On the other hand, it appears that in an fc edit session, vim sets `filetype=sh`. So you can create `~/.vim/ftplugin/sh.vim` that contains `set textwidth=0`, and add `filetype plugin on` in your `~/.vimrc`, and then you don't have to bother with anything special about invoking `fc`

Comment: thanks, but these all neglect my statements in my vimrc, is not usable.